Specific inputs giving anomalies in output function
I'm working on a project about AGNs where I'm simulating light curves and then applying the Structure Function (see Macleod 2012, Kozlowski 2017) to them, and coming across a problem when I input specific values. My model uses a burst function with Poissonian waiting times, where each burst corresponds to a shot shape of my choice (e.g. exponential or power law). This then creates a simulated light curve to which I apply the Structure Function.
My parameters are all determined by two inputs: the decay time (td) of the exponential shot and the average time between shots (ts). For now I have been keeping these as the same value.
e.g. ts = 20 and td = 20
my timestep is then 1% of td,ts so timestep = 0.2
the Structure Function takes different values of timelag, k, which are also defined by my input parameters, and created using np.linspace.
kmin = timestep*2 and kmax = td * 30
so will look something like this k = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8 ... 600]
My main problem is that for input values between 8 and 20, my log-log plot for the Structure Function shows odd deviations from the smooth curve, usually corresponding to the i = 5th and 10th values of my timelag.
My bursts are generated using this function, where
from numpy import random
lambd = 1/ts 
mu = lambd/increments
p1 = 1 - np.exp(-mu)

def burst_function(timemax, p1, increments):
    
    bursts = np.zeros(len(timemax)) # create burst array
    for j in range(len(timemax)):
        #determine how many bursts per timestep
        unittime = random.choice([1,0], size=increments, p=[p1,1-p1])
        bursts[j] = np.sum(unittime)
        
    return bursts

(I have been using increments = 100). For the example of an exponential shot shape, I then generate 3x the length of time for my light curve that I want to use by using
s = 0
for i in range(len(timemax)):
    if bursts[i] > 0: # if there is a burst
        s = bursts[i] + (s * exp(-1/td))
        result.append(s)
        
    else: # otherwise apply decay constant
        s = s * exp(-1/td)
        result.append(s)

And cut out the middle third to compute my Structure Function with.
Before doing this I also change my timelag list k so that it contains the relative difference between timesteps rather than absolute values.
lag = k/timestep
i.e. from k = [0.4, 0.6, ... 600] to lag = [2, 3, ... 3000] for timestep = 0.2
Here is my Structure Function code:
from tqdm import tqdm # using this just so I know how long I have left of the function running

def structure_function(timelength, lag, noisedata):
    SF = []
    noisedata = np.array(noisedata, dtype=np.float64)
    for m in tqdm(range(len(lag))):
        v_values = []
        k = int(lag[m])
        
        maximum = int(len(timelength)-k)
        for j in range(maximum):
            
            init = (noisedata[j+k] - noisedata[j])**2
            v_values.append(init)
                
        SF.append(np.sqrt(2 * np.mean(v_values)))
    
    return SF

Finally I do a log-log plot of k against SF.
example of my structure function for a 'bad' input td,ts=20
example of my structure function for a 'good' input td,ts=25
Sorry that this is so long!
Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I can fix this. Have already corrected for edge effects, and increasing the resolution of my simulation seems to just make the anomalies worse.

Specify all imports (besides numpy).  And example inputs if you expect us to run this code

@hpaulj have edited my question so that hopefully this makes more sense now!
